# UserCreationForm remains invalid - but no errors show up

Tags: django, django-forms

I use a UserCreationForm to add users without the admin panel. I added the form, but the validation fails without throwing errors.

This is for a small Django app where users should be able to sign up themselves. I tried giving access to the admin panel, which is not a suitable approach.

```py
forms.py 

from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import formset_factory

class KAP_add(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional.')
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional.')
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254,required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', )
```

```py
views.py
def kundenAdminPanel(request):

    formAdd = KAP_add()

    if request.method == 'POST':

        print(request.POST)
        print(formAdd.errors)
        print(formAdd.non_field_errors)

        if formAdd.is_valid():
            formAdd.save()
            print("Save")
        else:
            print(formAdd.errors)


    context = {
            'add':formAdd,
            }

    return render(request,'visDat/kundenAdminPanel.html',context)
```

```html
kundenadminpanel.html
            <form method="POST" name="add"  id = "add" >
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% bootstrap_form add %}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" id="tabl">Submit</button>                
            </form>
```

It should add a user to the database, or throw an error. Whatever I do, the form remains invalid, thus the save command is never executed. Any ideas why this might be the case? The errors section remains empty.

Comment: you are not giving any data to KAP_add form, so it is always empty. you need to do `if request.method == "POST": KAP_add(request.POST)`

Comment: This helped it...! I was blind.